# JavaScript How to group array of objects by value based on matched pattern of other array value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking for solution - group array of objects by value based on matched pattern of other array value.

have sample array

```
data = [
            {
                "Application": "Chrome - 567"
            },       
            {
                "Application": "File Transfer Protocol - 45"
            },
            {
                "Application": "Google APIs - 3618"
            },
            {
                "Application": "Google Generic - 943"
            },
            {
                "Application": "Google Search - 54"
            },       
            {
                "Application": "Microsoft - 2821"
            },
            {
                "Application": "Microsoft DFSR (Distributed File System Replication) - 3722"
            },
            {
                "Application": "Microsoft Remote Procedure Call - 742"
            },              
            {
                "Application": "Telegram- 2235"
            },        
            {
                "Application": "Facebook Videos - 2250"
            },
            {
                "Application": "Facebook - 690"
            }
           ]
```

> Other array

```
var Appdata = [Google, Facebook, Instagram, Microsoft, Telegram]
```

> expected result

```
result =  [
        {
            "Application": "Chrome - 567"
        },       
        {
            "Application": "File Transfer Protocol - 45"
        },
        {
            "Application": "Google"
        },    
        {
            "Application": "Microsoft"
        },                
        {
            "Application": "Telegram"
        },              
        {
            "Application": "Facebook"
        }
       ]
```

there are two separate array `data` and `Appdata` in `data` array if we match the string of `Appdata` array then it should replace with `Appdata` array value in original `data` array

kindly helps to find the solution for this array.

Comment: Why is that the expected result? For instance `"Application": "Google - 3618"` doesn't appear in the sample array so why should it appear like that in the result?

Comment: if we get  "Application": "Google " is also fine. let me update it please

Comment: why `File Transfer Protocol - 45` is in result when it's not in `Appdata`?

Comment: if we not matching it then it should be same as it is from `data` array

Comment: You really need to describe the relationship between the inputs (`data` and `Appdata`) and the output (`result`). Your current question is like asking "I have a list of brands and another list of clothes. I expect a list of clothing brands. Kindly help me find a solution." As you can see, there isn't enough information to know what you're even trying to do.

Comment: there are two seperate array `data` and `Appdata` in `data` array if we match the string of `Appdata` array then it should replace with `Appdata` array value in original `data` array

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
    {"Application": "Chrome - 567"},
    {"Application": "File Transfer Protocol - 45"},
    {"Application": "Google APIs - 3618"},
    {"Application": "Google Generic - 943"},
    {"Application": "Google Search - 54"},
    {"Application": "Microsoft - 2821"},
    {"Application": "Microsoft DFSR (Distributed File System Replication) - 3722"},
    {"Application": "Microsoft Remote Procedure Call - 742"},
    {"Application": "Telegram- 2235"},
    {"Application": "Facebook Videos - 2250"},
    {"Application": "Facebook - 690"}
];
const appData = ['Google', 'Facebook', 'Instagram', 'Microsoft', 'Telegram'];

for (let datum of data) {
    let appStr = datum.Application;
    for (let appDatum of appData) {
        if (appStr.includes(appDatum)) {
            datum.Application = appDatum;
            break;
        }
    }
}

const foundByAppStr = {};
const dataWithoutRepeats = data.filter(datum => {
    const appStr = datum.Application;
    const keep = !foundByAppStr[appStr];
    foundByAppStr[appStr] = true;
    return keep;
});

console.log(dataWithoutRepeats);
```

Comment: here result values should not repeat, it must be unique

Comment: Updated my answer to filter out duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const data = [
    {
        "Application": "Chrome - 567"
    },
    {
        "Application": "File Transfer Protocol - 45"
    },
    {
        "Application": "Google APIs - 3618"
    },
    {
        "Application": "Google Generic - 943"
    },
    {
        "Application": "Google Search - 54"
    },
    {
        "Application": "Microsoft - 2821"
    },
    {
        "Application": "Microsoft DFSR (Distributed File System Replication) - 3722"
    },
    {
        "Application": "Microsoft Remote Procedure Call - 742"
    },
    {
        "Application": "Telegram- 2235"
    },
    {
        "Application": "Facebook Videos - 2250"
    },
    {
        "Application": "Facebook - 690"
    }
]

const Appdata = ["Google", "Facebook", "Instagram", "Microsoft", "Telegram"];

const result = [...new Set(data.reduce((p, c) => {
    const found = Appdata.find(a => c.Application.includes(a));
    found !== undefined ? p.push(found) : p.push(c.Application);
    return p
}, []))].map(r => ({ Application: r }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

many ways to do this...

```js
const data = [{
                "Application": "Chrome - 567"
            },       
            {
                "Application": "File Transfer Protocol - 45"
            },
            {
                "Application": "Google APIs - 3618"
            },
            {
                "Application": "Google Generic - 943"
            },
            {
                "Application": "Google Search - 54"
            },       
            {
                "Application": "Microsoft - 2821"
            },
            {
                "Application": "Microsoft DFSR (Distributed File System Replication) - 3722"
            },
            {
                "Application": "Microsoft Remote Procedure Call - 742"
            },              
            {
                "Application": "Telegram- 2235"
            },        
            {
                "Application": "Facebook Videos - 2250"
            },
            {
                "Application": "Facebook - 690"
            }
];
const appData = ['Google', 'Facebook', 'Instagram', 'Microsoft', 'Telegram'];

const result = data.map(dataEntry => {
    const found = appData.find(it => dataEntry.Application.includes(it))
  if(found){
    dataEntry.Application = found
    return dataEntry
  } else return dataEntry
})
const filtered = result.reduce((acc, current) => {
    if(!acc.find(data => data.Application === current.Application))
    return acc.concat([current])
  else return acc
}, [])

console.log(filtered);
```